# Auto hide alert above navbar in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, navbar

Hello guys I'm trying to show you hide and nailed above navbar, I got it showing, but his animation it's not working while hiding .. Someone may help me fix it?

Check it out on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/qdk0pytx/)

// CSS

```
.margin-top-0 { margin-top: 0px !important; }
.margin-top-20 { margin-top: 20px !important; }
.margin-top-40 { margin-top: 40px !important; }
.alert-server {
  border-radius: 0;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}
```

// Shows #notificationBar

```
setTimeout(function () {

    // working
    $("#notificationBar").css({"display":"block"});
    $('#notificationBar').html('Hello User! Welcome!').addClass('margin-top-0', 2000);
    $('body, .navbar').addClass('margin-top-40', 2000);

}, 2000);
```

// Hides #notificationBar

```
setTimeout(function () {

        // not working
        $('#notificationBar').removeClass('margin-top-0', 2000).html().css({"display":"none"});
        $('body, .navbar').removeClass('margin-top-40', 2000);

    }, 6000);
```

// HTML

```
<body>              
    <div id="notificationBar" class="alert alert-success alert-server" role="alert" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999; margin-top: -40px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    </div>      

    <div class="navbar-spacer" style="min-height:60px;"></div>                  

     <!-- Fixed navbar -->
     <nav class="website-nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">                    
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="nav-center">
            </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Can you please add a JS Fiddle link.

Comment: Would you please check your browser console for errors and copy it to here so that we can figure it out?

Comment: @AhmedHammad I got no error in console.. It's hiding, but the animation while hiding is not working... I  want to see it  sliding up.

Comment: @Anji I'll paste it there

Comment: How about adding this to the margin classes: "transition: all 2s linear".

Comment: @vinoli   try this `$('#notificationBar').removeClass('margin-top-0', 2000).html('').css({"display":"none"});`

Either you can remove `html()` method or `pass empty string in the html() method`.

Comment: @anji http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/qdk0pytx/

Comment: @AhmedHammad http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/qdk0pytx/

Comment: error is same what i had mentioned in the above comment.  updated filddle link http://jsfiddle.net/qdk0pytx/2/

Comment: @anji pls see my fiddle again, I had update it... Now it shows its animation http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/qdk0pytx/6/

Comment: @Anji There's no need for a third party link when anyone can embed a working example directly in the question via a stack snippet using the `<>` button

Comment: @Vinoli problem for not hiding the welcome message is with `html() method` only. check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qdk0pytx/21/

Comment: @anji now it's working, but it's not smooth while hiding ... I want the reverse of the one used to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic solution.

Original non-fixed `.navbar` version http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/vr4xto0a/1/

With the fixed navbar, I have had to take a slightly different approach by adding the class on the body instead to reveal the alert as well animate the navbar position and increase the body padding.

See new `.navbar.fixed-top` version http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/1a620ho8/

```js
showAlert = function() {
  $('body').addClass('alert-show');
}

hideAlert = function() {
  $('body').removeClass('alert-show');
}

// auto show
setTimeout(function() {
  showAlert();
}, 1000);

// auto hide
setTimeout(function() {
  hideAlert();
}, 5000);
```

```css
@import "http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";

BODY {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  transition: padding .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}

.alert {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -50px;
  transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}

BODY.alert-show {
  padding-top: calc(4.5rem + 50px);
}

BODY.alert-show .alert {
  top: 0;
}

BODY.alert-show .navbar.fixed-top {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success mb-0 text-center" role="alert">
  I'm going to disapear in 5000ms
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Almost there, I want to use the jquery-ui's duration animation to get smoothness showing and hiding my alert. Take a look in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/qdk0pytx/28/

Comment: I've update the question to get a smooth show hide transition using css rather than loading in jquery-ui.

Comment: Awesome and so clean!! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, make sure your page loads with the `.alert-hide` class already on the alert element. If your alert exceeds the height of 50px in mobile for example, you might have to tinker the css with some media queries.

Comment: I tried to use it on my code, but there is one more question. I'm using a fixed navbar and doesnt works. May you change your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
showAlert = function() {
  $('body').addClass('alert-show');
}

hideAlert = function() {
  $('body').removeClass('alert-show');
}

// auto show
setTimeout(function() {
  showAlert();
}, 1000);

// auto hide
setTimeout(function() {
  hideAlert();
}, 5000);
```

```css
@import "http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";

BODY {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  transition: padding .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}

.alert {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -50px;
  transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}

BODY.alert-show {
  padding-top: calc(4.5rem + 50px);
}

BODY.alert-show .alert {
  top: 0;
}

BODY.alert-show .navbar.fixed-top {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success mb-0 text-center" role="alert">
  I'm going to disapear in 5000ms
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```